# Uncaught TypeError: menu is null

Tags: javascript

Задача: создать кастомное контекстное меню с функцией копирования выделенного текста. Что то получилось нагуглить и оно даже заработало тут:
https://jsfiddle.net/deletd/zwfvdg20/112/

Но к сожалению вне песочницы перестает работать.

Думаю что проблема в copyBtn (в самом конце).
Пробовал выводить как в отдельный файл .js так и внутрь контекстного меню

Консоль ругается на следующее:

> Uncaught TypeError: menu is null
>
> ```
> <anonymous> http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/js/newcontextmenu.js:60
> ```
>
> var menuItems = menu.querySelectorAll(".context-menu__item");
>
> ```
> <anonymous> http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/js/newcontextmenu.js:191
> ```
>
> })();

Направьте новичка на путь. Метод тыка и гугление исчерпались

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Перенесите скрипт в конец страницы.

Comment: Менять местами тоже пробывал. (это же имелось ввиду? https://jsfiddle.net/deletd/zwfvdg20/126/ ) Тогда ругается на эту строку: 
_Uncaught TypeError: copyBtn is null
   <anonymous> http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/js/newcontextmenu.js:5
copyBtn.addEventListener('click', function(text) {_

Comment: @del "Менять местами тоже пробывал" - ??

Comment: Разобрался. Да вы оказались правы, хотя я вроде это тоже проделовал ранее и не помогало. Сейчас все заработало, спасибо!

Comment: @deletd Пожалуйста. Знак "галочка" - слева от ответа.